Adding acknowledgments and abstract in PDF bookmarks and referring to them correctly
I am writing my MSc thesis. Everything is fine so far. I have frontmatter and mainmatter. In the fronmatter part I have acknowledgments and abstract. I need to have bookmarks in the .pdf file for 'contents', 'Acknowledgments', and 'Abstract'. I do not want them to be in the table of contents but I need them in the PDF bookmarks. I used \pdfbookmark{Acknowledgments}{toc} and \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc} to add the acknowledgments and the toc in the bookmarks and I successfully got bookmarks named 'Acknowledgments' and 'Contents'. But when I click the bookmark 'Contents' I go to the acknowledgments (the page before the toc), and even when I click the bookmark 'Acknowledgments' I go to the middle (approximately) of the page of acknowledgments rather than the top of the page.
How can I solve these problems?.
Here is my code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in, headsep=22pt, footskip=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter*{Abstract} \pdfbookmark{Abstract}{toc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter*{Acknowledgments} \pdfbookmark{Acknowledgments}{toc}
\lipsum[1-3]  
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc} % ADD CONTENTS IN BOOKMARKS
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{Introduction} 
\lipsum[1-7]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum[1-8]
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}


The second argument of \pdfbookmark is a label: it has to be unique!
For the table of contents, I explicitly add a pagebreak to put the bookmark on the right page.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in, headsep=22pt, footskip=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
  
  \frontmatter
  
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \pdfbookmark{Abstract}{Abs} % changed
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  

  \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
  \pdfbookmark{Acknowledgments}{Ack} % changed
  \lipsum[1-3]  
  
  \makeatletter
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
  \makeatother
  \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc} % ADD CONTENTS IN BOOKMARKS
  \tableofcontents 
  
  \chapter{Introduction} 
  \lipsum[1-7]
  
  \mainmatter
  
  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \lipsum[1-8]
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \lipsum[1-9]
  
\end{document}


Edit
If you want the link on the title, you have to manually \clear(double)page, insert the bookmark and then the \chapter, what is done for the table of contents. You can define a function for this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in, headsep=22pt, footskip=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\insertbookmarkchapter}{mO{#1}}{
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
  \makeatother
  \pdfbookmark{#1}{#2}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  
  \frontmatter
  
  \insertbookmarkchapter{Abstract}
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  
  \insertbookmarkchapter{Acknowledgments}
  \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
  \lipsum[1-3]  
  
  \insertbookmarkchapter{\contentsname} % ADD CONTENTS IN BOOKMARKS
  \tableofcontents 
  
  \chapter{Introduction} 
  \lipsum[1-7]
  
  \mainmatter
  
  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \lipsum[1-8]
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \lipsum[1-9]
  
\end{document}


This is not the best thing we can do. When I click the bookmarks 'Acknowledgments' and 'Abstract' it takes me to the middle of the pages of the acknowledgments and abstract rather than to the top of the pages (as for chapters, sections, introduction).

@HusseinEid, see the Edit.

This works as I want. Thanks for your help.

But why the page after the page of the list of symbols is left blank. I do not want this behaviour.

What do you mean? If the document is two-sided, you have \cleardoublepage that inserts a blank page before chapters.

Can not these blank pages be removed? This seems to be not a good solution for me.

Without more information, I can do nothing. Maybe you should ask another specific question.

Hi @NBur
I tried adding \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage immediately after \tableofcontents and it removed the black page.
